# `open -a Chrome` returns `Unable to find application named Chrome`

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I have `Google Chrome` installed on `macOS`. The file `/Application/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist` shows:

```
CFBundleIdentifier : com.google.Chrome   
CFBundleName : Chrome.
```

I am able to launch `Google Chrome` with `open -b com.google.Chrome`. But 'open -a Chrome' returns `Unable to find application named Chrome`.

How can I launch `Google Chrome`, or another generic app, with the syntax `open -a`?

[image: Screenshot with application details and error message]

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK with the -a option you need to use the full app name. So for Chrome, you have to use:

```
open -a "Google Chrome"
```

or

```
open -a "Google Chrome.app"
```

For other applications, e.g. Chromium, you need to use the value of the key `CFBundleName`, which you can find with:

```
$ grep CFBundleName /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Info.plist -A 1
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Chromium</string>
```

The utility `grep` looks for lines with `CFBundleName` in the file in the second argument, and the flag `-A 1` prints one line after the matching lines.

Comment: soga... Must run  `open -a  [value of CFBundleExecutable]`  , not [value of CFBundleName] .   Thanks u

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `open -a "Google Chrome"` as stated.

If someone like me is looking how to do it with `open -a "Chrome"` you can simply open finder go to applications and rename "Google Chrome" to only "Chrome". I dunno if this can have some serious implications for the program, I believe it shouldn't.